# python dict pop could not return pytorch tensor

Tags: python, pytorch

My code is as follows:

```
import torch

mydict = {"state0": torch.tensor(12345.6), "state1":torch.tensor(23456.7)}
print(f"mydict: {mydict}")

val = mydict.pop("state0")
print(f"val={val}")
```

The output is:

```
mydict: {'state0': tensor(12345.5996), 'state1': tensor(23456.6992)}
val=12345.599609375
```

Here why the pop() does not return tensor(12345.5996)? I need it to be a tensor instead of a scalar.

Comment: What do you get if you use `print(f"val={val!r}")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the previous answer, `pop` is not the issue.

The issue is when you format the string using the `f-string`. When you pass the tensor to the `f-string`, Python calls the `__format__()` method of the tensor object which converts the tensor to scalar.

To print the tensor object itself, directly pass it to the `print` function without using the `f-sting` formatter.

Or you can even use the `repr()` function:

```
import torch

mydict = {"state0": torch.tensor(12345.6), "state1":torch.tensor(23456.7)}

val = mydict.pop("state0")
print("val=", repr(val))
```